# OpenCL local work local memory

Tags: c, memory, opencl, local

I have a problem with local memory, concretely with save value. This is all kernels in file loaded to program.

```
__kernel void initData(int bitSample, int transmitorCount ,int bufferLen, __global short *sequence)
{

   __local int constData[2];
   __local short mask[(15 * 1023)];

   constData[0] = bitSample;
   constData[1] = bufferLen;

   for (int i = 0; i < transmitorCount * 1023; i++) {
       mask[i] = sequence[i];
   }

   printf("startPlace: %u \t Resutl: %i = %i\n", transmitorCount, constData[0], constData[1]);
   barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
}

__kernel void correlation(__global short *inBuffer, __global int *outBuffer, __local int *constData)
{

   uint startPlace = get_global_id(0);
   uint sequence = get_global_id(1);

   outBuffer[0] = inBuffer[0];

   printf("startPlace: %i Sequence: %i\t Resutl: %i = %i\n", startPlace, sequence, constData[0], constData[1]);
}
```

Program is working and local memory is saved. Initialization call is:

```
    size_t globaId[3] = { 1, 0, 0 };
    ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(gpuControlData->cmdQueue, gpuControlData->initKernel, 1, NULL, globaId, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

But when I start correlation kernel, saved values is in local only in first start. Second and next starts are wrong data. I try to init local memory before every start, but it doesn´t work. Create command to queue is:

```
while(true){
    ret = clSetKernelArg(gpuControlData->corelationKernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *) &inBuffer);
    ret = clSetKernelArg(gpuControlData->corelationKernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&outBuffer);
    ret = clSetKernelArg(gpuControlData->corelationKernel, 2, sizeof(cl_int) * 2, NULL);

    size_t globaId[3] = { 3, 2, 0 };
    ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(gpuControlData->maskCorrelQueue, gpuControlData->corelationKernel, 2, NULL, globaId, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
}
```

The result of one run is:

```
startPlace: 2    Resutl: 100 = 150000
startPlace: 0 Sequence: 0        Resutl: 100 = 150000
startPlace: 1 Sequence: 0        Resutl: 100 = 150000
startPlace: 2 Sequence: 0        Resutl: 100 = 150000
startPlace: 0 Sequence: 1        Resutl: 100 = 150000
startPlace: 1 Sequence: 1        Resutl: 100 = 150000
startPlace: 2 Sequence: 1        Resutl: 100 = 150000
oneIteration
startPlace: 0 Sequence: 0        Resutl: 1056562655 = 1058300571
startPlace: 1 Sequence: 0        Resutl: 1056562655 = 1058300571
startPlace: 2 Sequence: 0        Resutl: 1056562655 = 1058300571
startPlace: 0 Sequence: 1        Resutl: 1056562655 = 1058300571
startPlace: 1 Sequence: 1        Resutl: 1056562655 = 1058300571
startPlace: 2 Sequence: 1        Resutl: 1056562655 = 1058300571
```

So I need some help or example how to run kernels in loop with same local data?

Thanks for help.

Comment: If my memory serves, data in local memory are not retained between wavefronts. And I think I don't know what you wanted to do.

Comment: I want to compare data. One data is defined and static and Second data is change. So I want to save constant data to local memory for faster access. I have to chance inBuffer for every iteration.

Comment: @StepanRydlo all threads in a workgroup can gather data from global memory to local memory and they do it concurrently. so you can have single kernel doing both initialization and correlation. You need synchronization with a barrier command before starting correlation.

Comment: But If I will do both in one kernel, every kernel will copy from global memory to local memory in every start. And it not be faster. I want to save data to local variable when program start. And this data I do not want change. Is it possible to create it?

Comment: I create new test, and local value is saved on 126 iteration, and work group size i have 128.

Comment: gpu is running many kernels not just yours. cant save local. even if you could, there would has to be megabytes of local memory for all kernels running through gpu. also bottleneck isn't reassigning local, it is running a second kernel

Comment: Local memory is created to facilitate communication within a work group. It's unique for each work group and shared by all work items in that group. This is why it's impossible to be initialized before kernel is launched (because new local memory is created for each newly launched work group), and preserved after the kernel finishes ( you would need one copy for each work group).

Comment: OpenCL's memory model is mostly designed to enable computing, rather than to dictate memory hierarchy: global is shared by everyone, local is shared within a work group, private is exclusive to a work item, const could be shared or duplicated. XX memory is faster than YY is implementation defined. Be sure what you are doing and what you are working with before trying to "optimize" it.

Answer (score 2):

Local memory is essentially "scratch" memory and does not retain its contents after the end of the kernel. You typically initialize it inside the kernel to serve as manual cache. You can't do what you are trying to do with local memory.

You can use const memory to try to speed memory access. Const memory is likely to use the actual cache of the device and will have speed comparable to local. The only problem is that there is no way to guarantee (or know) if the memory gets cached - it could end up just being global. You need to experiment.

Comment: I would like to ask how to create constant global buffer. I dont find any example. I create buffer CL_MEM_READ_ONLY and in kernel I use argument __constant short *mask. But there is no different in fast. Sp how I create constant buffer?

Comment: how do you know constant memory is the bottleneck? did you check everything?

Comment: As long as constant memory is smaller than 16KB should be fine in any CL desktop device.

Comment: @StepanRydlo constant memory is any argument you pass to the kernel from the host that is not a pointer. Or pointers declared as "__constant". There is no function that speciallized to constant memory only.